# Populate a form field based on what was entered in another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a vendor working with a web app for creating forms using a GUI form designer.  I'm currently trying to populate an 'address' text field based on the 'organization' that was picked in another field.  The organization field is selected with a look up table (user clicks an ellipsis then chooses from a list).   In form designer I have the option to add scripting to an `On Change`, `On Load`, and `On Click` field.

We currently do the reverse of this on another form.  When user enters the zip code  then it auto populates the city field from a look up table in the system.  I just can't figure out how to or the coding in the `On Change` script field.

[image: OnChange text box script for ZIP code]

[image: Settings for the City text Field]

Any help would be great!

Comment: Please post the code in a snippet ([See illustration](http://i.imgur.com/p94EZRA.png?1)), [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), [PenCode.io](http://pencode.io), or [Plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co)

In addition, you should refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you want to auto complete the second field from DB on the bases of first?

Comment: @AGE - I don't think the OP wants to duplicate the value from one field to another.  I believe OP wants to use selection from first field as the input/parameter which determines the content of the second field.  Similar to a cascading drop down.

Comment: @devlincarnate fair enough, the answer provided below seems solid as well

Comment: @AGE, devlin carnate is correct.  User selects an organization from a look up table.  Then in the address text box it would populate the field based on the organization selected address.

Answer (score 1):

You can tie an event handler to the organization input to look for a change.  Then, based on the value of the organization input, set the value on the address input.  Here is a generic example:

**HTML**

```
<select id="org">
  <option value="">Choose Org</option>
  <option value="1">home</option>
  <option value="2">work</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="" id="address" placeholder="address">
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#org').change(function() {
  var addressVal = "";
  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case "1":
      addressVal = "100 Main St";
      break;
    case "2":
      addressVal = "500 Main St";
      break;
  }
  if (addressVal !== "") {
    $('#address').val(addressVal);
  }

});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hw7pszo4/)

Answer (score 0):

usually you can do something like this

```
$("#text-box-id").on("change", function() { ... });
```

now a days with HTML 5 and modern browsers you can do

```
$("#text-box-id").on("input", function() { ... });
```

Update -

```
$("#zipcode").on("input", function() {

    var zip = $(this).val();
    -- add your ajax call here and the response from the server update your controls with the values  --

});
```

I would also take it one step further and add a regex check around the onchange so that you are not firing an ajax call every-time you hit the key. You only fire it once your regex for a zip code has been met.

Comment: This answers the question of how to tie an event handler to an element.  It does not explain how to use the input from the first field as a parameter to get the content for the second field.